# CURL Nuget visual studio 2013 unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_init referenced in function _main()

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nugetgallery

I follow this link (http://echorand.me/2012/01/27/picloud-and-rest-api-with-c-client/.) and I get some libraries from Nugget (CURL, curlpp, curlpp redist, curlpp symbols).

But it have some error,
     unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_init referenced in function _main()
 please help me solve that problem.

This is image show error and nuget packages.
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/dADzy.png